# Can "if" have the meaning of "although" before a clause?

Tags: conjunctions

> Someone standing outside the Great Hall might well have thought some
>   sort of explosion had taken place, so loud was the noise that erupted
>   from the Gryffindor table. Harry, Ron, and Hermione stood up to yell
>   and cheer as Neville, white with shock, disappeared under a pile of
>   people hugging him. He had never won so much as a point for Gryffindor
>   before. Harry, still cheering, nudged Ron in the ribs and pointed at
>   Malfoy, who couldn’t have looked more stunned and horrified ***if***
>   he’d just had the Body-Bind Curse put on him.
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

*If* seems to have a meaning of ‘even though’, but [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/if) and [Merriam-Webster’s](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/if) only have cases used before adjectives to introduce contrasts. Can ‘if’ have the meaning of ‘even though’ before a clause, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*If* is used to introduce a **contingency**, something which *might* happen; here it introduces a counterfactual contingency, an event which has *not* happened. Malfoy was not cursed, but even if he had been cursed he could not have looked any more stunned.

*Though* or *although* is only used to introduce **actualities**, things which *have* happened. *Even though he had just had ...* would imply that Malfoy DID have the curse put on him, which is not the case here.